# ng-style fails while jQuery.css works OK

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have this div:
`<div id="outlineCSS" ng-style="elementOutlineStyle"></div>`
I have a `<ul>` with many `<li>` and when I hover one of them, with `ng-mouseover` I trigger a function that controls `elementOutlineStyle`, as follows:

```
$scope.elementOutlineStyle = angular.extend({
            'pointer-events': 'none',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'box-shadow': 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0px 0px 10px 0px',
            'display': 'block'
          }, {
            'height': data.height,
            'width': data.width,
            'left': outlineLeftPos,
            'top': outlineTopPos
          });
```

But this code applies with a DELAY! Let me explain: say I hover `<li>` #1, nothing happens, and if I hover `<li>` #2, then style with #1's data is applied.

HOWEVER, if I replace the angular code with this one:

```
         $("#outlineCSS").css({
              'pointer-events': 'none',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'box-shadow': 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0px 0px 10px 0px',
            'display': 'block',
              'height': data.height,
            'width': data.width,
            'left': outlineLeftPos,
            'top': outlineTopPos
          }
         );
```

Then it works as intended... How come angular is lagging on this one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style change must be wrapped in `$scope.$apply`.

Comment: isn't ng-mouseover supposed to trigger a digest? i think we're missing something. a fiddle would be helpful.